# i made chrome extension but it's works only after refresh site

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

i made a chrome extesion for study that just works capture a bunch of youtube screen and merge it.

[(like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDOHn.png)

it works but only after refresh site.

i doesn't know javascript well but it looks like my extension unloaded at other page. (so when i refrsh the youtube. the site looks like loading something)

**manifest.json**

```
{
"name": "some text that not on english",
"description": "some text that not on english",
"version": "0.1",
"manifest_version": 3,
"action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_icon": {
"16": "/icons/icons8-capture-16.png",
"32": "/icons/icons8-capture-32.png",
"48": "/icons/icons8-capture-48.png",
"128": "/icons/icons8-capture-128.png"
}
},
"content_scripts":\[{
"js": \["contentscript.js" \],
"matches":\["https://www.youtube.com/watch\*"\],
"run_at": "document_end"
}\],
"permissions" : \[
"storage", "activeTab", "scripting","tabs"
\],
"host_permissions": \["*://*/\*"\],
"icons": {
"16": "/icons/icons8-capture-16.png",
"32": "/icons/icons8-capture-32.png",
"48": "/icons/icons8-capture-48.png",
"128": "/icons/icons8-capture-128.png"
}
}
```

**popup.js**

```
<pre> <code>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');

    captureButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'capture' });
        });
    });
    
    saveButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: 'save' });
        });
    });

});
```

**contentscript.js**

```
let k=0;
let obj=\[\];
var image = 0;
let imageheight = 0;
let imagewidth = 0 ;

function picture()
{
let canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),video=document.querySelector("video"),ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width=parseInt(video.offsetWidth),canvas.height=parseInt(video.offsetHeight),ctx.drawImage(video,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
imageheight = canvas.height
imagewidth = canvas.width
var base64ImageData1=canvas.toDataURL("image/webp");
return base64ImageData1;
}

function Imagepic(){
var image = new Image();
image.src=picture();
obj\[k\] = image;
k++;

}

function mergepic(){
let canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),video=document.querySelector("video"),ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
let canvas3=document.createElement("canvas"),video3=document.querySelector("video"),ctx3=canvas3.getContext("2d");
canvas3.width=parseInt(video3.offsetWidth),canvas3.height=parseInt(video3.offsetHeight*k);
for (var i=0; i\<obj.length; i++)
{
console.log("a");
ctx3.drawImage(obj\[i\],0,imageheight*i);
}
var base64ImageData=canvas3.toDataURL("image/webp"),o = new Date(0),p = new Date(video3.currentTime\*1000),filename="Capture\_"+new URL(document.location.href).searchParams.get("v")+"\_"+document.title+"@"+new Date(p.getTime()-o.getTime()).toISOString().split("T")\[1\].split("Z")\[0\]+".webp",
a=document.createElement("a");
a.download=filename,a.href=base64ImageData,a.click();
obj=\[\];
k=0;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.action === 'capture') {
Imagepic();
} else if (request.action === 'save') {
mergepic();
}
});
```

Comment: 1) Remove all \ 2) Remove `watch` from `matches` because youtube is a SPA, 3) You need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension.

Comment: it works compleletly well, thanks!